# What is the correct way to use a dynamic framework in other dynamic frameworks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

**Question:** 
What is the correct way to use a dynamic framework in other dynamic frameworks? 
(without pods or other package managers)

**Problem:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/B.framework/B
      Referenced from: A.framework/A
      Reason: image not found
```

**What I have:** 
A.framework (dynamic framework) 
B.framework (dynamic framework) 
MainApp.xcodeproj

In my case, I want to use B module in A module.

The only way at the moment to fix the problem below is to: 
1. add B.framework in both A.framework and MainApp

The problem with this solution is that you have to add B.framework two times and you have to maintain both of them in two places.

**What I would prefer:** 
1. add B.framework in **just** A.framework. 
OR 
2. add B.framework in **just** MainApp and use B across the other frameworks.

Is it somehow possible to achieve one of these?

**Other "solutions" that failed for me:** 
1. link B.framework + add "Runpath search path" in A.framework for `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/B` 
2. link B.framework + create "copy files phase" in A.framework and copy B.framework + new run script in MainApp with a code signing script for A.framework and it's dependencies

Comment: This should just work, if A and B are both dynamic then if you just add B to A and build it (it shouldn't compile in, it will just be a dependancy) then in the main app you import A, and when you build it will fail saying you need to import B to the Main app itself

Comment: @AngryDuck Yes it works this way but I’m looking for a solution to add B only once in either A or MainApp. So I don’t have to maintain B in both A and MainApp. For example is Foundation.framework added in both A and MainApp or is just added to the MainApp?

Comment: but in this case its not actually in A, A Is simply dependant on a particular version of a framework, so any app that uses A needs to use the correct version of the framework its dependant on

Comment: @AngryDuck Exactly, but the problem is that I cannot add a dependency for B in A without linking it and to link it I have to add B in A.

Comment: I don't think your understanding how this works.... your not maintaining it in two places, you are depending on it in your main app because your framework requires it, you only maintain in one place (the framework) when the framework changes, you need to update the app because its using the framework ....

Comment: So you add B in both A, MainApp.. and you maintain only in MainApp?

Comment: Well whatever B is let's say it's an open source library, and framework A is going to rely on it, so if a new version fo framework B comes out and you wan to use it then youd change A to work with the new version and add the new version  to A and build it. Now since A is dependant on a new version of B your main app will need to comply with A's dependencies, so if you add A to main app it will say that it need the correct version of B, so import the correct version of B in main app too, make sense?

Comment: If a new version of B comes out
1. update A with the new version
2. update MainApp with the new version

this is not maintaining in two places?

Comment: Your not maintaining anything in the main app your just putting a new version in because you are using a framework that relies on another framework, A will actively need code changes to keep up to date and continue using B. Since your app uses A and A relies on B then you just need to make sure that main app always has latest version of B in it. Try ignoring the fact you are devving the framework too (I assume you are) if you were just the main app all you need is to import frameworks and their dependencies

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I don't want to rely very much on the MainApp to update all the dependencies A requires. Basically, that's what I just want to do, to keep frameworks only in A. For example if you add static frameworks only in A, MainApp does not require any static frameworks from A.

Comment: Yea because they are static therefore they are compiled into A and when you import A you are actually importing A and all its dependencies (which btw isn't really standard practice or looked upon well) so with a dynamic framework you dont have a choice if its dependant on it then you have to include it in the app, you could use a dependency manage to do it for you if you want but I can never be bothered with those for xcode they dont seem very good

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time and clarifications.